# Python AST - Operator Node to Accommodate Two or More Child Nodes

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, abstract-syntax-tree, bnf

**CODE:**

```
class UnexpectedToken(Exception):
    def __init__(self, token, index):
        self.token = token
        self.index = index
        self.message = f"Unexpected token `{token}` at index {index}"


class OperandMissing(Exception):
    def __init__(self, token, index, nth):
        self.token = token
        self.index = index
        self.nth = nth
        self.message = f"Missing {2 - nth} operand(s) for the operator `{token}` at index {index}"


def compile(tokens):
    try:
        tokens_with_index = [_normalize_token(token, i) for i, token in enumerate(tokens)]
        ast, unprocessed = _compile(tokens_with_index)
        if len(unprocessed) > 0:
            raise UnexpectedToken(unprocessed[0][0], unprocessed[0][1])
        else:
            return ast
    except (OperandMissing, UnexpectedToken) as err:
        print(err.message)


def evaluate(ast):
    if type(ast) == tuple:
        return _evaluate_tuple(ast)
    else:
        return ast


def _compile(tokens_with_index):
    if tokens_with_index == None or len(tokens_with_index) == 0:
        return 'noop', []
    token, index = tokens_with_index[0]
    if _is_operator(token):
        child1, unprocessed = _compile(tokens_with_index[1:])
        if child1 == 'noop':
            raise OperandMissing(token, index, 0)
        child2, unprocessed = _compile(unprocessed)
        if child2 == 'noop':
            raise OperandMissing(token, index, 1)
        return (token, child1, child2), unprocessed
    else:
        return token, tokens_with_index[1:]


def _evaluate_tuple(ast):
    operator, child1, child2 = ast
    if operator == 'ADD':
        return evaluate(child1) + evaluate(child2)
    elif operator == 'SUB':
        return evaluate(child1) - evaluate(child2)
    elif operator == 'MUL':
        return evaluate(child1) * evaluate(child2)
    elif operator == 'DIV':
        return evaluate(child1) / evaluate(child2)


def _is_operator(token):
    return token in ['ADD', 'SUB', 'MUL', 'DIV']


def _normalize_token(token, index):
    if _is_operator(token):
        return token, index
    else:
        try:
            return int(token), index
        except ValueError:
            raise UnexpectedToken(token, index)


tokens = 'ADD SUB 1 2 MUL 3 DIV 10 2'.split()
print(f"Tokens: {tokens}")

ast = compile(tokens)
print(f"AST: {ast}")

result = evaluate(ast)
print(f"Result: {result}")
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Tokens: ['ADD', 'SUB', '1', '2', 'MUL', '3', 'DIV', '10', '2']
AST: ('ADD', ('SUB', 1, 2), ('MUL', 3, ('DIV', 10, 2)))
Result: 14.0
```

**PROBLEM:**

`ADD`, `SUB`, `MUL`, and `DIV` only expects two expressions. I tried my best to implement the logic (below) into the code but to no avail. I am supposed to adjust the program functionality:

(1) `ADD` will expect 3 expressions and `SUB` will expect 4 expressions. While `MUL` and `DIV` expects still the same, expects 2 expressions.

(2) Flexibility is more satisfying like having variable configurations like this:

```
ADD_expects = 3
SUB_expects = 4
MUL_expects = 2
DIV_expects = 2
```

The only accepted configuration is 2 or above.

---

**QUESTION:**

What should be the proper adjustment for the `_compile()` function? Or other affected functions?

---

**P.S.:**

Please do not give unhelpful/savage answers. Please ignore this thread if you have the savage intention to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Not a Python expert, but you could implement the algorythm in pseudo code bellow:

```py
    expects = {"ADD": 3, "SUB": 4, "MUL": 2, "DIV":2}
    # ...
    # ... inside _compile(...)
    if _is_operator(token):
      list = [token]
      unprocessed = tokens_with_index[1:]
      for _ in range(expects[token]):
        arg, unprocessed = _compile(unprocessed)
        list.append(arg)
      return tuple(list), unprocessed
    else:
      return int(token), tokens_with_index[1:]
```

The idea is to have a list of the number of arguments for each operator in `expects`, and build the resulting tuple dinamically, instead of in fixed steps.

Comment: Thanks it helps. I've inserted code after `arg, unprocessed = _compile(unprocessed)` (line #8) :::

`if arg == 'noop':     raise OperandMissing(token, index, 0)`

But it is now inaccurate in pointing out the faulty token and its index & inaccurate expected remaining token. What is the fix?

Comment: As it is pseudo code, I didn't insert any error handling. But it seems to me that after calling ```arg, unprocessed = _compile(unprocessed)``` inside de loop you should check for "noop", jus as you were doing in your original code.